# Xamarin form display alert pop up appear 2 times

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

i have created Xamarin pcl form project and ask confirmation when user press the logout button, its working fine both android and iOS but at the same i run as windows UWP project the pop up appears 2 time, i don't what happen. Please guide me some one how can i fix this issues.

i mentioned my code below what i used in my project.

I have used both option with await and without await keyword but no luck.

```
var resp = await DisplayAlert("","Are you sure want to Logout?","Yes", "No");
if (resp)
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the user is pressing the button to fast 2 times, I suggest you add a flag, something like this:

```
bool displayFlag = false;
if(!displayFlag)
{
    displayFlag = true;
   var resp = await DisplayAlert("","Are you sure want to Logout?","Yes", "No");
   if(resp)
   {
        //Logout
   }
   displayFlag = false;
}
```

Or Maybe the Alert message is inside another Task (Just imaging) so Maybe this can help:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainthread( () => async 
{ 
    await DisplayAlert("","Are you sure want to Logout?","Yes", "No");
});
```

Comment: I used this code but no luck 
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async()=> {
                await DisplayAlert("", "Are you sure want to Logout?", "Yes", "No");
            });

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the popup by calling `await DisplayAlert`. By storing it into a variable, you're just saying that you want to get the output from the popup (Yes or no). The second popup is because you added it to your if condition. You should just do this:

```
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(new Action(async () =>
  {
       if(await DisplayAlert("", "Are you sure want to Logout?", "Yes", "No"))
       {

       }
  }));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have used above code but no luck 

Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(new Action(async () =>
                        {
                            if (await DisplayAlert("", "Are you sure want to Logout?", "Yes", "No"))
                            {

                            }
                        }));

Comment: Your comment makes no sense, this is HOW it supposed to be used, see: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups/

Comment: Yep, like he didn't try that out. There was a bug, that's why he's asking it here in SO.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this error, and both answers didn't work for me. However, I managed to find what was causing it and fix it. It was being caused by my application calling the `LoadApplication()` method multiple times. Once in the `OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs eventArgs)` method, and a second time in the `OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)`, whilst the application is running.

So, if people are still running into this, make sure this isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem.

I was binding an EventHandler (+=) to a Control many times, so the alert was showing n times.